# Database Location of PhoneGap Hybrid application in Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-sqlite, android-debug

I have a phonegap application . I want to know how can i debug the database for that particular application and what is the location on the file system where it is stored.

I checked in DDMS but File Explorer is not showing anything(I have Cyanomod on my android phone). Also checked /data dorectory on file system and not able to find the physical database file.

Can someone helpout.